# copy clipboard permission denied for an apk running with chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, apk

When I do

```
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.url)
```

on an apk running on chrome 93

I get this error :

```
 DOMException: Write permission denied.
```

the navigator.permissions is undefined, how do I define permission to copy-past on chrome?

I use ionic 5 to generate the apk from an angular app and chrome 93.04577.82

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do that using `navigator`. But, you may try to do that installing the plugin for the Ionic [Clipboard](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/clipboard).

Comment: It's not compatible with my ionic version

Comment: So, please explain which are the `Ionic` version you are using. You didn't mention before a specific version at the question.